# How to retrieve parent key from firebase using java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2` key, How to do so?
Here is my code

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //addListenerForSingleValueEvent
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Object response = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    System.out.println("read data :"+response);
                }
            });
            ref.child("chatmessage").child("devicetoken").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
//                  Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
//                  System.out.println("previousChildName :"+previousChildName);

                    }
                }
});
```

Here is the Firebase database

[image]

I tried using child data snapshot method but did not worked. Any help for this will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your `ref` value? The code you provided doesn't seem to match your database structure.

Comment: Under the `Following` node, there also others nodes besides `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2` or it's the single one?

Comment: no there are multiple nodes under houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2 @AlexMamo

Comment: I haven't asked you if there multiple nodes under `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2`, i have asked you if 
 `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2` is the only one node under `Following`. The value if this node `houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2` you want to find, it's correct?

Comment: correct, houfxWvbwyVmbHX60IGjpNkZR9w2 is also multiple node under Following